# How to convert a math equation (summation) to a code?

Tags: c

Using two functions:

- Factorial Function
- Power Function

Develop a C program for the following equation:

[image]

I've done this . but no output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double factorial(double x);
double Power_function(double y);

int main(){
  double answer=0;
  double n;
  double y;

  printf("Enter Y :The last limit of the summation:>");
  scanf("%ld",&y);
  for (n=1;n<=y;++n){
    answer=answer +factorial(n)*Power_function(n)*y;
  }

  printf("The Answer is %0.2f\n",answer);
  return 0;
}

double factorial(double x)
{
  double ans;
  if (x==0){
    ans = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ans = x*factorial(x-1);
  }
  return ans;
}

double Power_function(double y){
  double ans;
  ans=pow(2,y);
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: Homework? Looks like it.

Comment: I suppose this is homework. Please add the corresponding tag.

Comment: How would you compute that equation manually? That's an algorithm that will do to start with.

Comment: Yeah homework , I don't want anyone to solve it , I just need a hint or what can I do with it ..because I don't know anything about this

Comment: Have you been going to class? have you been reading the book? have you asked the teacher any questions?  Why do you not know anything at all about a topic from class?

Comment: The whole problem is math, not programming :)

Comment: @binarylife What have you tried so far?

Comment: How you posted these mathematical symbols?

Comment: @binarylife: Math or programming, it doesn't matter.  This problem would not be assigned in class if you did not already have the opportunity to acquire the necessary knowledge.  If you don't understand the math symbology, it is because you missed a class or weren't paying attention.

Comment: @abelenky : well ,I missed some ..and I'll do it by myself . Also thanks for your help .

Comment: @Vikram.exe it is an image , I used a website to make it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't do everything for you, but here is a basic outline.

You must finish it off.

```
int answer = 0;
int n;
for(n=1; n <= y; ++n)
{
    answer = answer + (n! * 2^n)*y;
}
```

Comment: @binarylife: notice that this is pseudocode, ! and ^ in C++ don't mean factorial and power (actually they are the binary not operator and the bitwise xor operator).

Comment: darn it @matteo: I was looking forward to him struggling with that!  I even gave him clues that he has to finish it off.

Comment: @abelenkey, he said he already has the functions :P

Comment: @abelenky: I'm with you for the "maieutic" approach, but putting in the wrong operators is plain evil. `:)`

Comment: @Muggen:  His problem states that he is allowed to use those two functions.  However, OP has not demonstrated that he knows the names or syntax of those methods.

Answer (score 2):

I've a suspicion what one of the learning outcomes of this is and too much help here will give the game away.

I think i can safely say you need to break each part of the equation down to smaller solvable parts.

The three biggest parts are summation, N Factorial (N!) and 2 to the power N

The summation is effectively a loop with N starting at 1 and ending at y, so look for the C syntax to write a loop (hint there are two common types, while and for)

The other two are functions, if your allowed to use premade functions then plenty exist only a google away which will sort you out nicely, if not you'll have to write your own.

factorial is `n*(n-1)*(n-2)...(n-(n-2))*(n-(n-1))`

so `4! = 4*3*2*1`

a prime candidate for a [recursive function](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=recursion) or a function with a descending loop in it

2 to the power n is 2 multiplied by itself n times

so 2 to the power 2 = `2*2`

2 to the power 3 = `2*2*2` and so on

Once again a loop looks like a good place to start with that.

After that its just a matter of using your two functions inside the loop, giving the user a way to input Y and testing with some numbers.

1,2,3 would be a good start as they're nice and easy to work out on a calculator.

All well and good so far I'd hope, -1 should make interesting things happen to every example I've seen posted so far, and that's before we start pushing the boat out with big numbers like 32.

Edit:
Right, I've taken a look at your code, and it looks like your problem isn't in the implementation of your algorithm, its not reading the variable in correctly, outputing y just after you set it yields 0, so something isn't working quite right there.  Im not a c coder but i had a quick hack at it with some liberal googling and your non functional code and made it read an argument in then parse it to a double.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
double factorial(double x);
double Power_function(double y);

main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  double answer=0;
  double n;
  double y;
  y = atol(argv[1]);
  //printf("%lf\n",y);
  for (n=1;n<=y;++n){
    answer=answer +factorial(n)*Power_function(n)*y;
  }

  printf("The Answer is %0.2f\n",answer);
  return 0;
}

double factorial(double x)
{
  double ans;
  if (x==0){
    ans = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ans = x*factorial(x-1);
  }
  return ans;
}

double Power_function(double y){
  double ans;
  ans=pow(2,y);
  return ans;
}
```

So essentially your code with a different input method,

compiled using

`gcc so.c -lm`

executed as

`./a.out 1`
yields `The Answer is 2.00`

`./a.out 2`
yields `The Answer is 20.00`

`./a.out 3`
yields `The Answer is 174.00`

Pen and paper maths backs it up so your algorithm is sound so far!

Feed it some negative numbers and some huge numbers to see what it does from here!

Comment: I've done almost exactly what you said , and I've posted the code .But it doesn't give me output .

Comment: @binarylife - edited my answer re. your comment.  Have a word with you're lecturer/lab supervisor to see why you're original method didn't read the input correctly, I've not got the experience with c to debug it myself so i cheated and did it a different way!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the sum of (n! * 2^n) from 1 to y.

```
total variable is 0  
for 1 until y:  
multiply factorial(n) and pow(2, n) and add this to total
end of loop
print out total
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to write down what you manually would do to work that equation out. Try out 1 to 5, for example, and see what you get.